# Why can't i acces remote Windows Server through MacBookPro?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, remote-desktop, mac

I'm trying to access a client MacBookPro to Remote Server using Remote Desktop Application "RD Client" I connected a VPN to that server. BUT But in the application when I fill the remote information with the username and password I get "Error Code 0x204", Firewall is off What possible solutions i can do?

Thank you
Mo'min

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting by domain name or via IP?
Try connecting with IP and see if you get a different response.

You can also ensure the connection is actually possible by using telnet in Terminal as so: `telnet <ip address> 3389`

I would also recommend testing your credentials via a Windows PC to ensure there are no issues with your access.